# What reference do I need to make NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext() work?

Tags: ravendb

The documentation says to use this call if you want to view the Management Studio with the embedded version, yet every tutorial seems to leave out how to make it work.  I am already referencing Raven.Client.Embedded, but it does not recognize NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext()

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Currently referencing:

using Raven.Client.Embedded;
using Raven.Database;

Comment: Fixed the issue, had to reference Raven.Database.Server

Answer (score 0):

It is in Raven.Database.dll, you need to reference that.